# Is there a name for verbs written as: Katakana+る?

Tags: verbs, katakana

The number of verbs that have the pattern `KATAKANA + る` seems to be increasing. Some examples include ググる, ダブる, トラブる, バグる, パニクる, etc.

Is there some kind of official name (or even informal name) for these specific types of verbs? It's not quite the same as wasei eigo, as far as I can see.

Comment: 参考： https://osaka-kyoiku.ac.jp/_file/gakusei/kikaku/gakudayori/166/campus_kotoba.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linguistically, this kind of word is a bit like a **blend** or a **portmanteau**, where two (or more?) words are munged together.  [In Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B0%E3%82%93%E8%AA%9E), these are called either 鞄【かばん】語【ご】 (a calque of "portmanteau word") or 混成語【こんせいご】 (a calque of "blended word").

In these cases, your sample verbs would be blends of the borrowed term and the verb-forming element -る.

However, since the second portion is really only an ending, these might not be *quite* the right kind of combination to qualify as blends.  Broader categories to which this kind of word belongs include **neologisms** or [造語【ぞうご】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%A0%E8%AA%9E), and **composite words** or [合成語【ごうせいご】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%88%E6%88%90%E8%AA%9E).

While researching for this answer, I happened upon [the サボる article in the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%82%8B#%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AB%E6%96%BC%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE), which lists a few of these verbs and explains that 「このような造語法【ぞうごほう】はかなり例外的【れいがいてき】であるといえる」.  I suspect that this phenomenon is recent enough that formal academic linguistic terminology might not be settled yet.

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen them termed as "coined verbs" as they are a hybridization of foreign loan words (Japanized) into verbs.